# how to create test class and folder from android studio?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-studio, junit4

I want to build unit test from existing android project but the test folder and test class like `androidTest` and `test`  are **deleted**. Because this is existing project and I dont know why previous developer deleted them, so I need to create new test folder for this to work.

I try add the libraries to my gradle like [this](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html#build) :

```
// Required -- JUnit 4 framework
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // Optional -- Mockito framework
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
```

and create `test` folder and the test class inside `src` folder but still not works and I can't run the test.

any idea what the correct steps to achieve this in android studio? since the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html#build) only showing how to add the test library and the test class but not where to place test folder or create new test folder.

Comment: Well, at least within eclipse (and tools that maven that have similar ideas), you would **not** put your test code in the same project. Instead, you have a second project that contains all your test code. But as I am not a user of AndroidStudio I can't tell if this tool wants you to do things differently.

Comment: Agreed, but the thing is this project is already on android studio :)

Comment: What is preventing you from creating **another** project?

Comment: in andorid studio when creating project, the test folder like andoridTest and the test class is genereated automatically, I tried to follow the same pattern. and I think the structure of test  in android studio is different from eclipse.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create a directory for your testing source code, i.e. src/test/java. You can do this from the command line or using the Project view in the Project tool window. The new directory should be highlighted in green at this point.

Also make sure to choose the correct build variant.

For more details on how to configure all this and run the tests properly,  please refer http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support

Hope this helps.